# Android MediaPlayer network location

Tags: java, android, network-programming

i'm attempting to direct a custom media player app to my web server, but when I start the app it forse quits. the only thing I can think of is this line of code:

`private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("192.168.0.100/audio/");`

This works perfect for an internal address (/sdcard/), but not for a web address. any thoughts?

I'm an extreme novice as well. :P

Comment: please post the exception from your logcat

Comment: 04-12 16:49:29.483: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.openword.airborne/com.openword.airborne.openword}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-12 16:49:29.483: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-12 16:49:29.483: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

Answer (score 0):

Try `"http://192.168.0.100/audio/"`, i.e., with the http:// prefix.